# If base+fibres are connected, is the total space connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, connectedness

I have a morphism $f: X \to Y$ of smooth varieties over an alg. closed perfect field $k$.

> If $Y$ is connected and all the fibres of $f$ are connected, does it follow that $X$ is also connected?

If not, what further conditions on $f$ would guarantee that $X$ is connected?

Comment: Consider the inclusion of two points into a connected variety with more than two points.  Surjectivity is one condition that gives you what you're looking for.